# any performance concerns using a predicate applied to a column projection of _table_suffix?

Tags: google-bigquery

Need to be able to create a view using a wild card table specification.

Subsequently allow queries expressed against the view to filter by _TABLE_SUFFIX.

i.e bq mk  --nouse_legacy_sql --view="select  * from `bigquery-public-data.fec.cc*`" schema.viewname

and select count(*) from schema.viewname where _TABLE_SUFFIX ...

The parser will not support the _TABLE_SUFFIX reference in the prior example and thus forced to include a column projection of _TABLE_SUFFIX.

bq mk  --nouse_legacy_sql --view="select _TABLE_SUFFIX as tableid, * from `bigquery-public-data.fec.cc*`" schema.viewname

If a query such as select count(*) from schema.viewname where tableid='l100' be specified is Biquery able to optimize the predicate and in the same manner as when _TABLE_SUFFIX is specified?

Answer (score 0):

Using standard SQL, you can define a view that includes _TABLE_SUFFIX (for wildcard tables) or _PARTITIONTIME (for partitioned tables), though you'll need to give the column an alias in the select list. If you query the view and filter on the column, only the relevant subset of data will be scanned rather than the whole table.

See more details here - https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=202&can=1&q=_TABLE_SUFFIX